# Cannot open Master Design Layout

Tags: sitecore-rocks

I am a complete beginner and barely touched the surface of Sitecore in general.

My problem did occur while following the ["Getting started" tutorial](https://youtu.be/i3Mwcphtz4w?t=1232), where the tutorial showed the Design Layout through Sitecore Rocks of the `master/sitecore/content/home` item.

[image]

### The problem

It simply does not open the Design Layout screen and I do not know what else I should check. It does however work with the "web" database (`web/sitecore/content/home`)

Now this might *not* be a problem, as I might as well use the "web" database for the same purpose. But I would like to strictly follow the tutorial before I go my own way.

I feel like I am missing something completely, hopefully somebody can help me or at least point me in the right direction.

(I am not sure if this is a suitable question for this Stackexachange community)

### Specifications

- Sitecore rocks 2.0.39.0
- Visual studio 2015 Community
- SQL 2014
- Windows 10 Pro x64

**Log Errors**

> ManagedPoolThread #5 19:38:55 ERROR Unable to connect to server localhost:27017: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:27017.
>
> 11100 19:38:55 ERROR Data template '{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}' not found for item '/sitecore/content/Home' in 'master' database
>
> 11100 19:38:55 ERROR Failed to load content editor warnings
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException...

Comment: It's suitable :-)  And welcome to SSE.

Comment: Do you know which version of Rocks your using and which version of VS?

Comment: @Anicho Totally forgot, updated my answer with my specifications.

Comment: Check your Sitecore logs and see if any errors have been added. You should find them in your instance folder `\Data\logs`

Comment: @RichardSeal Thanks, I found multiple errors after trying to open the Designer. Updated the answer with the relevant errors.

Comment: Do you get the same error in content editor? If you do I would check your connection strings and make sure everything is valid and the user you are logging in with has the proper permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reproducable Issue

I have been able to reproduce your issue in Sitecore Rocks, using your setup. The problem that you are experiencing is that the "Sample Item" template is missing from your installation.

On a working environment, you should have the following template displaying in Sitecore Rocks:

[image]

Upon inspecting this template, you will see that the Item ID of the Template is indeed the Item ID being displayed in Error that you provided:

[image]

When this template does **NOT** exist in the database that you are trying to view the **Design Layout** of the Sample Home Item `/sitecore/content/Home`, ***Design Layout and Sitecore Rocks does absolutely nothing***.

### To Resolve:

Because this looks like a Vanilla Instance of Sitecore (Welcome to Sitecore BTW!) my suggestion is that you drop your **Master** database from SQL, and re-attach a vanilla Sitecore Database as Master (be mindful of your ConnectionStrings.config file). You can find a copy of the Sitecore_Master.MDF in the Sitecore Zip Archive off of http://dev.sitecore.net for the version of Sitecore you're using.

Or, just simply reinstall Sitecore using either the EXE Installer (again off of dev.sitecore.net) or the [Sitecore Instance Manager](http://dl.sitecore.net/updater/sim/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Reinstalling the instance solved the issue, though I am still unsure what would have caused this. The item did seem to exist in the database and manually re-attaching the database files did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

My gut is that it's something to do with this ID reported in your logs:
{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}

You should be able to search for this data template in your master database using the content editor. If you can't find it, I would then switch to the web database and search there as well.

If the item is in the web but not master, check your recycle bin in case it's been deleted.

Check the user connecting via rocks has access to the item you find.

It could also be that the reference to this item doesn't exist in web yet, so a publish might mean it's also broken in web.